# How to open a binary file in my case .nii file using node.js

Tags: node.js, buffer, file-format, nifti

I want to open a binary file, or at least when I try to open this with the vscode editor, is say that, can't be opened, because is a binary file.

Can someone explain to me what I can do in order to open this type of files and read the content?

About the .nii file format. is a *NIFTI1* and used on medical visualization like MRI.

What I trying to do is to read this file at the lowest level and then make some computations.

I will like to use Node.js for this, not any Python or C++.

More details about the file format can be found here.

> https://nifti.nimh.nih.gov/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about how *VScode* handle binary file but for exemple with *Atom* (or with another text editor like *vi*), you can open and view the content of a binary file. This is not very usefull however as the content is not particularly human readable, except maybe some metadata at the top of the file.

```
$ vim yourniifile.nii
```

Anyway, it's all depends on what you want to do with that file, which "computation" you're planned to apply to it, and how you will use it after that.

Luckily, there are some npm packages that can help you with the task of reading and processing that kind of file, like [nifti-reader-js](https://github.com/rii-mango/NIFTI-Reader-JS) or [nifti-js](https://github.com/scijs/nifti-js), for exemple:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const niftijs = require('nifti-js');

let rawData = fs.readFileSync('yourniifile.nii');
let data = niftijs.parse(rawData);
console.log(data);
```